# Sorted Insert in linked list

Tags: linked-list

Given a problem to insert a new node within a sorted linked list in the correct position, I have come up with the following solution.

```
void SortedInsert(node** headref, node* newnode) {
  node* prev = NULL;
  node* curr = *headref;
  for (; curr; ) {
    if (curr->info > newnode->info) {
      break;
    }
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  if (!prev) {
    newnode->next = *headref;
    *headref = newnode;
  } else {
    newnode->next = prev->next;
    prev->next = newnode;
  }
}
```

Does this work.
Are there any edge cases this does not work for. Is there a simpler solution.

Comment: _Does this work._ Have you tested it with some cases of your own?

Comment: Compiles fine. Works while adding in front, middle, end. Is there a simpler method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making curr point to the node before which you want to insert, make curr point to the pointer that points to the node before which you want to insert.

Comment: Huh? current actually points to one node after "to be inserted" node.

Comment: @shreyasva Yes, my grammar was technically correct there, but then again English is my native language. Your code points curr at a node. You want to insert before that node. So curr points to the node after the newly inserted node. It comes to the same thing.